# How can I show up Dev Tool on electron window on which have multiple BrowserViews?

Tags: angular, electron, devtools

One of my electron Browserwindow is using multiple BrowserViews to embed webcontent into window. And these BrowserViews will be set according to the tab's selection created on window. I am able to open dev tools of these BrowserViews(it will open in separate windows) but I cannot show up the dev tool of the window itself.it is visible before setting the BrowserView on window. After setting a BrowserView on Window, it is laying behind the BrowserView. How can I show up this dev tool of window over the Browserview?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try open the devtool with `detach` mode
`win.webContents.openDevTools({ mode: 'detach' })`